# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - CORS

Tags: javascript, json, cors

I try to fetch content via `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var url = 'http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/SLN/guest/sln/woj.json'

    if (XMLHttpRequest) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ('withCredentials' in request) {
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.withCredentials = 'true';
        request.withCredentials = 'true';
        request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        request.send();
    }
}
```

I am getting next message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/SLN/guest/sln/woj.json.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

How to fix this? I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `*`

continu my problem with url : [jsonp continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112000/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-when-use-jsonp)

Comment: Pls refer to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work . It will help you understand and fix the above issue .

Answer (score 2):

You attaching `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on frontend, but that header shall be added while handling requests on server side. Server should attach `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Request-Method` headers to response that's permit performing requests for frontend.

My guess is that you cannot modify way the server handles requests and server doesn't support [JSON Padding (JSONP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), **so you have to use [JSON Proxy](https://jsonp.afeld.me/) to fetch that json data ...**

See [How to add CORS support to server](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) article and [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work?rq=1) SO question to get more info regarding CORS.

Comment: url http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/SLN/guest/sln/woj.json'
 is not my service...

Comment: @user7172 JSON Proxy is a tool which would help you, see updated answer

Answer (score -3):

CORS is browser only thing.

When you try to access some resource from current origin(current domain) to another domain, browser block this request.

Now the server or whatever that is you're hitting to get resource wants to whitelist your domain it can does so by adding some headers.